# SSL Connect Error

Tags: ruby, ssl, osx-mavericks, savon

My company recently provided me with a modern MacBook Pro running OS X 10.9.5.

We have a ruby application that makes SOAP requests to an external service to authenticate users. Since the upgrade to the new machine, I get SSL Connect Error whenever trying to make a SOAP request.

I am using the ruby Savon Client to make the SOAP calls, though we are version locked to a pre-1.0 version. The savon client is configured to use the correct cert_file, cert_key_file, cert_key_password, and the ca_cert_file.

I have access to an older MacBook Pro that is running OS X 10.8.4. I have set the 10.8 machine up exactly the same as the 10.9 machine. When the 10.8 machine makes the exact same SOAP call, there are no SSL errors.

I am at an absolute loss for what the cause of the error could be. I'm assuming that it must be some system library but that's as far as my guess goes.

Comment: Try: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/123150/437

Comment: I tried the solution in that post but there were no DigiCert certificates in the "login" keychain. I have also tried adding my DigiCert CA certificate to the "login" keychain and set it to always be trusted. This did not resolve my issue.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running? Is it the built-in Apple-supplied Ruby, or was it installed via RVM or rbenv or Homebrew? Seems to me OpenSSL isn't installed by default, or, if it is, it's out of date, and that I had to install it using Homebrew, then compile a Ruby to take advantage of it. I use rbenv on my laptop, but RVM would work as well.

Comment: I am not using the system default ruby. I have install ruby 1.9.3-p392 via rbenv. There is a system default version of openssl (0.9.8za) which is a similar version to the one on the Mountain Lion comp.

Comment: What is the error, and what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens on certain platforms/configurations.  You can solve it with the following steps:

1. Download this file and place it somewhere accessible:  http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Set an environment variable called SSL_CERT_FILE. The contents of the environment variable should be the path to the cert file you downloaded.
3. Close and re-open any terminal windows you have open.
4. Try your script again.

Taken from the following website:  http://richonrails.com/articles/solving-the-ssl-verify-problems